# Play specific part of mesh animation in three.js

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, mesh

I've loaded a three.js animation in using the FBX loader. The animation is a series of very short mesh animation in one file, total duration 2.8 seconds.

Is it possible to play certain sections of the animation and then stop?

For example:
animation 1 : from 0.1 seconds to 1.1 seconds.

(for use at the start of the game)

animation 2 : form 2.3 seconds to 2.5 seconds.

(for use between levels).

I've looked at the AnimationAction docs and I can't see how to do this.
The animation object comes in with anim animations[] array with 1 animation.

The animation works fine if I loop it all, it's all there.

Thanks,

Steve.

Comment: It's not supported currently. See [this discussion](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/clipaction-select-range-to-play/1134/14); there are some proposed workarounds.

Answer (score -1):

Steve.

There is a property named `time` and method `setDuration` in `AnimationAction`, you can try.